# Vuejs code change does not appear in website

Tags: php, vue.js, hosting, laravel-5.4, vps

I developed laravel 5.4 project, and then hosted it, and I setup nodejs and other packages on server, but when edit in vuejs code, the change does not appear in the website.
I also run `npm run dev` but it shows error for me this is error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules 
config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in your laravel project folder?